# Is it possible to setState to add new entry to beginning of object with numbered keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that contains a `number`, `text`, and the time when it was `created`. When the function gets triggered, I want to `setState` to add a new key-value entry into the beginning of this object:

```
this.state.object = {
   '0': {
       'number': '6041234567',
       'text': 'hello world',
       'created': 1531748662    
   },
   '1': {
       'number': '4384321234',
       'text': 'second message',
       'created': 15317489823  
   }
}
```

The new entry would look something like this:

```
'0': {
    'number': 1234567,
    'text': "this is a new text",
    'created': 1531748892    
}
```

and I want to add it to the beginning of the of the object.

This is what I have but it's creating completely new entries, and most importantly the problem is that *it's overriding the first entry*.

```
this.setState({
    ...this.state.recentMessages, this.state.recentMessages: 0 {
       'number': 1234567,
       'text': "this is a new text",
       'created': 1531748892  
    },
});
```

Comment: Objects don't have a "beginning". Use an array if you want to impose an ordering by some sort key (like an index number).

Comment: There is no real order in an object. Consider using an array instead, and that way you can easily add new ones: `this.setState({ recentMessages: [newMessage, ...this.state.recentMessages] });`

Comment: Also a given property name (like `"0"` in this case, if I'm reading it right) can only be present in an object once.

Comment: recentMessages is an object, those 0 and 1 numeric keys are just properties of the object. My point is, unless you turn recentMessages into an array, else it's pointless for your question because sequencing for properties in object is not predictable. They don't give you a fix sequence

Comment: In that case, how would I turn `recentMessages` into an array? Do I have to iterate through the object and add to a new array?

Comment: You can use `Array.from(object)`, but I would suggest to simply write this object as Array from the start

Comment: @42tg ... which again may not have the desired ordering because object keys do not have a predictable ordering.

Comment: @trixn but Arrays have an ordering... use `unshift()` to put it in the front

Comment: @42tg I know that arrays have an ordering but you can't create an array with the expected ordering from an object that does not have an ordering just by calling `Array.from()` with it because `Array.from()` also iterates over the object properties in a way that is not determined.

Comment: @Sam Do you get this data from an API, or why do you store it as an object?

Comment: @Tholle yes this data is from an API

Comment: @Sam Alright. Consider transforming the API response into an array before you put it in state if that makes life easier for you. `var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(k => parseInt(k, 10)).sort().map(k => obj[k]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that, you want to show new record on the top of the list.

I created a sample application, which will add new item on the top.
https://codesandbox.io/s/olqmo1z6yq

Gist is that, records are added to the end, but in `render()`, data is sorted in descending order by array key, which is retrieved by Object.entries.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { data: [] };
  static number = 1;

  addData = e => {
    const newItem = {
      number: App.number,
      text: `text ${App.number}`,
      created: 15317489825
    };
    App.number++;

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const data = [...prevState.data, newItem];
      return { data };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const sortedData = Object.entries(data)
      // sort in descneding order, showing the Latest message first.
      .sort((a, b) => b - a)
      .map(entry => {
        const [key, item] = entry;
        const { text, number, created } = item;

        return (
          <div key={key}>
            <span>{text}</span>
            <div>Number: {number}</div>
            <div>Created: {created}</div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        );
      });

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addData}>Add New Data</button>
        {sortedData}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```